# Find URL for images uploaded to Amazon S3

Tags: css, angular, amazon-s3

I have a uploaded the images in S3 bucket but how to apply the url path in CSS background images

```
.banner { background: url("/assets/images/banner.jpg") no-repeat}
```

Comment: Open the image in the browser directly then Copy that url in the css or provide the S3 image url will give the solution

Comment: okay sure  will do

Comment: suppose whenever change the url in s3 bucket than change the every css file url ?

Comment: Yes you have to change. But why are you changing the url every time?

Comment: No i have small doubt

Answer (score 0):

use the complete URL, but don't forget to make it public. One more thing i would like to add , in properties go to metadata and provide cache-control for better performance. max-age=31536000